# Automatic allocation failing when casting from integer to real(dp)

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

I don't know whether I'm hitting a compiler bug or missing something. I'm attempting to run the following code:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp=kind(1.d0)

  integer,  allocatable :: int_mat(:,:)
  integer,  allocatable :: int_mat_2(:,:)
  real(dp), allocatable :: real_mat(:,:)

  allocate(int_mat(2,2))
  int_mat = 0
  int_mat_2 = int_mat
  real_mat = int_mat ! Falls over here.
end program
```

Compiling and running with `nagfor (flags: -f2003 -C=all)` works as expected. Compiling and running with `gfortran (flags: -std=f2003 -fcheck=all)` fails at runtime with the error message:

```
At line 13 of file test.f90
Fortran runtime error: Array bound mismatch for dimension 1 of array 'real_mat' (1/2)
```

I would expect the code to succeed, as `int_mat_2` and `real_mat` should be allocated implicitly. This seems to be happening correctly for `int_mat_2` but not for `real_mat`.

I have tried this with various gfortran versions (5.4, 6.3, 7.0), and all have the same problem.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Add a specific version if necessary.

Comment: FWIW I think that `gfortran` is in error here.  I agree with `nagfor` that the code conforms to the recent standards.  Interesting (perhaps) that `gfortran` compiles the code if I replace the offending statement with the near-equivalent `real_mat = RESHAPE([1,2,3,4],[2,2])`, and that the revised code runs without error.

Comment: This is probably [this compiler bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52162).

Comment: It works under gfortran 10.2. Thus, it got fixed at some point. @VladimirF should this question be closed?

Comment: @jack Or answered, pointing out the bug linked by francescalus, probably as a community wiki answer. Not sure what close reason would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found by francescalus, this was [this compiler bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52162), which has since been fixed for more recent gfortran versions.